# How to insert data to a bootstrap modal in MVC

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i applied the `BootStrap` modal of my **MVCOnlineShop** , this is what i made so far:
[image]

and this was my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>OnlineShop - MVCOnlineShop</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MVCOnlineShop</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">OnlineShop</p>
                <div class="list-group">
                    @using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row carousel-holder">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                            </ol>

                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$24.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">First Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>See more snippets like this online store item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">15 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$64.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Second Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">12 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$74.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Third Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">31 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$84.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Fourth Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">6 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$94.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Fifth Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">18 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; My MVCOnlineShop Website 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <!-- /.container -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now after i changed my `_Layout.cshtml` into this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>OnlineShop - MVCOnlineShop</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MVCOnlineShop</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

@{
    // stores the Session content in a var
    var Categories = Session["Categories"] as List<Category>;
}

@*Checks if the Session variable is correct*@
@if (Categories != null)
{
    <ul>
        @*For each category in the Session var, display the link*@
        @foreach (var Category in Categories)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName, "Browse", new { Category = Category.CategoryName })
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">OnlineShop</p>
                <div class="list-group">
                    @using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row carousel-holder">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                            </ol>

                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$24.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">First Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>See more snippets like this online store item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">15 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$64.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Second Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">12 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$74.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Third Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">31 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$84.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Fourth Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">6 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$94.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Fifth Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">18 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; My MVCOnlineShop Website 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <!-- /.container -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

i got this :
[image: Image2]

how can i make these categories applied to the `Bootstrap Modal` , and getting the same design as it was with services,about and contact , thanks!
and this is my `CategoryController.cs`:

```
using MVCOnlineShop.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCOnlineShop.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        OnlineStoreEntities storeDB = new OnlineStoreEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Category/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Categories = storeDB.Categories.ToList();
            return View(Categories);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Category/Browse
        public ActionResult Browse(string Category)
        {
            // Retrieve Category and its Associated Products from database
            var CategoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Products")
                .Single(g => g.CategoryName == Category);

            return View(CategoryModel);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Category/Details
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var Product = storeDB.Products.Find(id);

            return View(Product);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Category/Browse?Category=Games

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the HTML being emitted by your second example and how does it differ from the first one?

Comment: check the 1st layout there was services about and contact , i replaced it with: from // stores the Session content in a var
    var Categories = Session["Categories"] as List<Category>; ..................till @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName, "Browse", new { Category = Category.CategoryName })
            </li>
        }
    </ul>

Comment: Yes, but the styling and any other bootstrap functionality doesn't operate on the server-side Razor code, it operates on the resulting client-side HTML.  So your first step would be to examine that HTML and see how it differs from the working example.

Comment: ohh ok , i have this category controller , what should i do to see them here in bootstrap model? like any online shop @David

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking in that last comment, but to see your resulting HTML you would view the page source or the browser's debugging tools.

Comment: the categories listed in the second image , how to make them applied to the bootstrap and with the design of it @David , i want them to be displayed on the top bar where there was the contact,services and about

Comment: You need to *look at the HTML* that's being rendered in the browser and *see how it differs* from the working example.  Nobody here can see your HTML code from your screen shots.  Screen shots are just flat images, they're not actual interactive windows into your web browser.

Comment: i am a beginner in mvc , give me the steps please to make this @David

Comment: Using your web browser has nothing to do with MVC.  All you have to do is find the "view source" option in your web browser, or the debugging tools.  F12 usually opens the debugging tools in many browsers.  The "view source" option is usually on a menu somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some classes that are required by bootstrap for your navbar.

First:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Needs the `collapsed` class added.

Secondly, you have a `<ul>` nested within `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`. You need to remove the outermost element (`<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`) and add the classes `nav navbar-nav` to the `<ul>` within your `foreach` loop.

**UPDATE:**

**navbar-toggle**

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

**Nested** 
Remove beginning and end tags for:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @using MVCOnlineShop.Models; @*LEAVE THIS*@
    ...
</ul>
```

And add classes to the conditional `<ul>`

```
@if (Categories != null)
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @*For each category in the Session var, display the link*@
        ...
    </ul>
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

**Issue with content padding**

According to your images, you have 10 categories displayed as list items in your navbar. Considering the length of some of those categories and the default bootstrap padding of the anchor inside of the list item (`padding: 10px 15px`) my best guess is that your menu items are wrapping.

In your page content `div` you should add another class. Like `body-content`

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container body-content">
    ....
</div>
```

Then add padding to that class in your CSS file.

```
.body-content{
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: can you please edit this on my Layout , because i am a beginner in MVC , need some help please @Kramb

Comment: ohhh it worked , thanksss , but how to get the image 800x300 down more , because it is behind the bar @Kramb

Comment: @Ahmad My best guess is that the image issues stems from the amount of `<li>`s in your nav. Either decrease the amount of list items, or add padding to the outermost container. You can do this by adding an additional class to `class="container"`and add `padding-top:` until it is at the desired location.

Comment: thanksss , it worked , but i want to move the image a bit more to the bottom @Kramb , how to do that